# Reading multiple analog inputs in cRIO 9045 through LabVIEW RT

Tags: input, real-time, frequency, labview

We are currently running real-time simulations using CarSim software with the CarSim Solver for LabVIEW-RT package. The simulations are being run on a cRIO 9045 in which, in addition, we introduce two analog inputs that simulate a brake pedal (with a load cell) and a steering wheel (with a small potentiometer).

The image below shows the LabVIEW VI we are using for this. In the lower left part of the block diagram we perform the reading of the physical ports of the cRIO that we are using for the analog inputs. We use the DAQmx channel creation and reading blocks. Then we condition the signals obtained from the sensors before sending them as input to CarSim.

We are new to LabView and think that we are probably programming the data acquisition wrong, since cRIO should deal with it without any problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have described your setup, but could you also tell us what is actually not working?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing *DAQmx Start Task.vi*. Use it before Timed Loop, after Timing configuration. That Start Task.vi will trigger data acquisition - so then AI channels will be read in the Timed Loop. Also, after Timed Loop you need to use *DAQmx Stop Task.vi*, in order to stop task. You could check any example for AI reading, directly accessible in LabVIEW Example Finder.